# libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, redhat, openldap

I was trying to uninstall openldap but now what ever command i am trying with `yum` i am getting

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: it's better to ask on SuperUser: `yum` can't find the file above, so it won't run; you have to reinstall openldap manually (or at least the library)

Comment: i do not want to install manually and i am login as root user in machine

Comment: locate yum binary with `which yum` (it should be `/usr/{s}bin/yum`); run `ldd yum_full_path`; if it outputs a line like `libldap-2.4.so.2 => not found` then libldap it's a runtime dependency for yum and it must be installed (or you could recompile yum removing ldap support, if it's possible)

Comment: # ldd /usr/bin/yum
        not a dynamic executable

Comment: then it's one of the module yum uses to fetch files, like curl (it uses ldap); anyway, I think libldap it's not an optional library

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1323

Comment: Thanks i checked this link but i remotely accessing server so not able to put CD

Comment: does `rpm` have this problem too? if not, you can reinstall (almost) safely ldap

Comment: But i am not sure which rpm i have to download can it do it in Red-hat like we do in ubuntu by package manager? I am just started work on red-hat so not able to resolve issue

Comment: I am manually downloading from here  http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27634265/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/openldap-clients-2.4.39-8.el6.x86_64.rpm.html